# OpenSSL decryption

Tags: go, encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I have encrypted string and asymmetric RSA key. The string was encrypted by PHP and its function `openssl_public_encrypt` with public part of the key and PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. I want to decrypt encrypted string with Go lang and private part of the key.

I know how to decrypt it in PHP:

```php
<?php

$encrypted = file_get_contents('./encryptedString.txt');
$privKey = file_get_contents('./private.key');

openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $decrypted, $privKey);

print_r($decrypted);
```

I know how to decrypt it in Bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cat encryptedString.txt | base64 -d > encryptedString64.txt
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in ./encryptedString64.txt -inkey ./private.key
```

I want to decrypt the string in the same way in GO lang. I've already tried some function from `crypto/rsa` package:

```golang
func DecryptString(privKey *rsa.PrivateKey, encryptedString []byte) ([]byte, error) {

    decryptedBytes, err := rsa.DecryptOAEP(sha256.New(), nil, privKey, encryptedString, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return decryptedBytes, nil
}

func GetPrivateKey() (*rsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    pemString := `******************`

    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pemString))
    parseResult, _ := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    key := parseResult.(*rsa.PrivateKey)

    return key, nil
}
```

...but I'm still getting error "crypto/rsa: decryption error" or empty results. What am I missing?

Comment: Please try not to suppress error message in GetPrivateKey func.

Comment: Which padding did you use when encrypting the string?

Comment: @GariSingh `OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING` was used as a default padding for that PHP encrypt function. Which is I believe equal to 1.

Comment: Since you do not explicitly specify the padding in PHP, the default is used, PKCS#1 v1.5. `DecryptOAEP()` applies OAEP as padding, as the name suggests. Try `DecryptPKCS1v15()`.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you, I've already tried it with `DecryptPKCS1v15` but this time I'm getting error `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. Could you be more specific how to build my func?

Comment: Post the full code with the `DecryptPKCS1v15()` call. You can find examples in the Go documentation, e.g. [here](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.3:src/crypto/rsa/pkcs1v15_test.go).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your comments. I have solved it and I am posting the solution below.

```golang
func main() {
    privateKeyB, err := ioutil.ReadFile("private.key")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to read private key - " + err.Error())
    }
    block, _ := pem.Decode(privateKeyB)
    parseResult, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to parse private key - " + err.Error())
    }
    privateKey := parseResult.(*rsa.PrivateKey)

    encStringB, err := ioutil.ReadFile("encryptedString.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to read encrypted string - " + err.Error())
    }
    encString64, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(encStringB))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to decode encrypted string to base64 - " + err.Error())
    }

    decryptedB, err := rsa.DecryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, privateKey, encString64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to decrypt string - " + err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println(string(decryptedB))
}
```